# How to set cache expiry date

Tags: performance, iis, caching, iis-6, browser-cache

Trying to cache a large js file on the client browser. When I check firefox's cache information, it shows the js to expire on 12/31/1969. I'm using IIS6 and have tried adding the following code to the web.config:

```
  <staticContent>
     <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
```

Still the same. How can I get the browser to cache this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, right click on your Site node and click Properties. Go to the HTTP Headers tab, tick `Enable content expiration` and set an expiry time.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure that in IIS, I'm not sure that IIS6 honors that web.config setting like IIS7 does.